# Which IronPython editor I can use to develop scripts for Tibco Spotfire controls

Tags: python, ironpython, tibco, spotfire

Can we use any IRONPython editor to develop scripts for Tibco Spotfire controls.

Can we use IDLE editor to develop IRONPython scripts for Tibco Spotfire? If yes then how to integrate the tibco module with IDLE editor, Can anyone help on this??

Comment: i donno much about tibco spotfire , but if you are looking for some editor where you could write python scripts, You can use "pyCharm community edition",
it is higly configurable to run IronPython scripts too. or you can configure it according to your needs.

Comment: If you want to extend the TIBCO Spotfire platform, you need to use the Spotfire SDK that requires Visual Studio to create plugins or spk (spotfire packages) that need to be deployed on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use any development tool (ide) which supports ironpython. One of the best in my point of view is PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio), just search for it. But when you want some thing very lightweight with only some syntax hilighting, i prefer using Visual Studio Code or Atom. But PTVS has a lot of nice features. One of the most important ones are those for debugging, because they prevent you from using some console printing or some thing similar as debugging tool. Just take a look at it.

**EDIT**

As far as i can see, it should work just fines with PTVS. Taking a look at this, is't just some API as any other api: [API-Doc](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Configure/ScriptingIntroduction.aspx)

Comment: What does Tibco Spotfire makes different from other modules? So short: yes it works with custom modules, otherwise an IDE would not be very helpful besides syntax-hl. Or what do you mean with *work*?

Answer (score 1):

Spotfre has its own IDE for developing scripts but it is very poor one when analysing its functionalities. I dont think you can use any IDE to debug the scripts but you can at least use the one suggested by BendEg to make creation of the code more 'pleasant'.

Answer (score 1):

Spotfire uses IronPython, which is a .NET implementation of python. In other words, is .NET driven by python.  To test simple python functions, you can use [CodeSkulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org/), a cloud based python interpreter. For IronPython, you can use this [java based online version](http://ironpython.net/try/) but again, this is to test simple scripts